# SUBMIT JOB IN TSO ERROR

Tags: submit, mainframe, jcl, tso

I am learning mainframe programming now. I got a tso id with Dezhi and I am using PASSPORT terminal emulator.My user is CATIA81

I uploaded  a few jobs and a cobol program to test. I tried to submit a job through the ISPF COMMAND SHELL:

```
 SUBMIT CATIA81.KSDCRTJ1.JCL
```

AND I GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR:

```
 SUBMIT cancelled, JOBNAME must start with CATIA81
```

This is what I have

```
    //CATIA81KDEL1 JOB CSBL81,CLASS=1,MSGCLASS=0,NOTIFY=CSIP1
    //* *******************************************************************
    //*        This program is provided by: SimoTime Enterprises          *
    //*           (C) Copyright 1987-2012 All Rights Reserved             *
    //*             Web Site URL:   http://www.simotime.com               *
    //*                   e-mail:   helpdesk@simotime.com                 *
    //* *******************************************************************
    //* Subject: JCL to delete a VSAM Data Set using the IDCAMS Utility   *
    //* Author:  SimoTime Enterprises                                     *
    //* Date:    January 1, 1998                                          *
    //*-------------------------------------------------------------------*
    //* The following example is more than what is usually required to    *
    //* delete a VSAM Data Set. However, the purpose is to illustrate the *
    //* functions of the IDCAMS utility.                                  *
    //*********************************************************************
    //*
    //         EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
    //SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*
    //SYSIN    DD  *
      DELETE    CATIA81.DATA.VKSD0080   -
                FILE (VKSD0080)          -
                PURGE                    -
                ERASE                    -
                CLUSTER
      SET       MAXCC = 0
     /*
    //
```

The orginal JOBNAME was KSDDELJ1, which I altered to CATIA81KDEL1. 
What was(were) my mistake(s)?

Comment: you dont need to mention the userid for your questions :)

Comment: You often do, as your userid is usually your TSO prefix, which ISPF adds to dataset names when you don't enclose them in quotes. It's also important in RACF violation messages etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Job names can be no longer than 8 characters, change the job name from  CATIA81KDEL1 to CATIA81K

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. I changed the job name to begin with the userid, due to the error message, and forgot to check that.

Comment: I changed the name, I really though it would work buu it didn't. the same error happens.

Comment: The message is sussinct. Your job name must begin with your userid, which leaves you with only one character. Verify your JOB card.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the job name cannot be longer than 8 characters, you also want to enclose your data set name in quotes unless you don't want it to be explicitly fully-qualified.  Otherwise, TSO adds your user prefix to the front of the name.

The prefix normally matches the user ID but can be set differently using the TSO PROFILE command.  To see what is defined in your environment, you can run this little REXX-script:

```
    /* REXX */
    say 'sysvar(syspref):' sysvar(syspref) 
    say 'sysvar(sysuid): ' sysvar(sysuid)
```